# How to use specifice blocks from another html file in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose I have 2 files `base.html` and `home.html`.

`home.html`:

```
{% block block1 %} b1 {% endblock %}
{% block block2 %} b2 {% endblock %}
{% block block3 %} b3 {% endblock %}
... and many more
```

`base.html`:

```
<!-- need extending other files so it is not an option. -->
{% extends 'othertemplate.html' %} 

{% include 'home.html' %} <-- I only want block2 from this file here.
```

How do I do this when displaying 'base.html'?

Comment: `more than 50 blocks` - rethink your template structure. Extract some blocks into separate util-templates and `include` them when needed, perhaps some of template parts will be more comfortable to use as template tags. Also you have upside down hierarchy: usually `base.html` is the root of template hierarchy - why does it include `home.html` in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Pass some conditions inside variable using `{% include 'template' with variable=variable_condition %}` and in home.html use

```
{% if variable == 'condition1' %} 
    {% block block1 %} b1 {% endblock %}
{% elif variable==`condition2` %}
    {% block block2 %} b2 {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

This should work.

Comment: That is why I have written "... and many more" in the question. There could be more than 50 blocks in home.html. Also, I may need to include more than 1 block. Is there any better way to do it instead of wrapping every block with if statements?